# Minkowski's bound for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm using Minkowski's bound $\mu_K$ to calculate class groups.

As an example I'm given for $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$ that $\mu_K=\frac{\sqrt{19}}{2\pi}$, but by my calculation $\mu_K=\frac{2!}{2^2}\frac{4}{\pi}\sqrt{19}=\frac{2\sqrt{19}}{\pi}$.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: In what sense are you *given* that the Minkowski bound is $\sqrt{19}/(2\pi)$? Have you considered that it might be wrong?

Comment: I've read the example of finding the class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$ and am trying to use the same process in other number fields, but as my calculation disagrees with example I'm wondering if the example is wrong or if I've missed something.

Comment: I realise the word 'given' was misleading

Comment: I meant *where* are you finding it said that the bound is $\sqrt{19}/(2\pi)$?

Comment: I calculated the same thing as you. It is impossible that $\mu_K=\frac{\sqrt{19}}{2\pi}$, because then $\mu_K<1$ implies that the class number is $<1$.